# Derive$~\frac{1}{2}\left\{\sin\left(2\alpha+\beta\right)+\sin\left(\beta\right)\right\}~$from$~\sin\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\cos\left(\alpha\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I want to derive the below RHS from the below LHS .

$$\sin\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\cos\left(\alpha\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\sin\left(2\alpha+\beta\right)+\sin\left(\beta\right)\right\}$$

Especially, the coefficient of  $~ 2 ~$ of  $~ \sin^{}\left(2 \alpha + \beta\right)  ~$ is currently the bigget part of the problems .

I've only came up of $$~ \sin^{}\left(\alpha + \beta\right) = \sin^{}\left(\alpha \right) \cos^{}\left(\beta\right) + \cos^{}\left(\alpha \right) \sin^{}\left(\beta\right)  ~$$

Which formula(s) can be used at here to derive the RHS from the LHS?

**ADD**

$$  \sin^{}\left(\alpha \right) = \frac{  \exp\left(j \alpha \right) - \exp\left(-j \alpha \right)   }{  2j  }  $$

$$  \cos^{}\left(\alpha \right) = \frac{  \exp\left(j \alpha \right) + \exp\left(- j \alpha \right)   }{  2  }  $$

$$  \sin^{}\left(2 \alpha  + \beta\right)  $$

$$ = \sin^{}\left(\alpha  + \left(  \alpha + \beta \right) \right)= \sin^{}\left(\alpha \right) \cos^{}\left(\alpha + \beta\right) + \cos^{}\left(\alpha \right) \sin^{}\left(\alpha + \beta\right)   $$

$$  \therefore ~~ \sin^{}\left(2 \alpha + \beta\right) - \sin^{}\left(\alpha \right) \cos^{}\left(\alpha + \beta\right) = \underbrace{\cos^{}\left(\alpha \right) \sin^{}\left(\alpha + \beta\right)}_\text{LHS which I firstly wrote .}   $$

Comment: I came up one idea .

Comment: you know the complex formula of sine and cosine? With those formulas the problem is not so hard.

Comment: I think I know it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)\cos(\alpha)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\cos^2(\alpha)\sin(\beta)=\frac12\sin(2\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\cos^2(\alpha)\sin(\beta)=\frac12\sin(2\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\frac12\cos(2\alpha)\sin(\beta)+\frac12\sin(\beta)=\frac12\sin(2\alpha+\beta)+\frac12\sin(\beta)=\frac12(\sin(2\alpha+\beta)+\sin(\beta))$$

Progressing from between steps requires some algebra and the following identities:
$$\sin(A+B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)$$
$$\sin(2A)=2\sin(A)\cos(A)$$
$$\cos^2(A)=\frac12+\frac12\cos(2A)$$